# Can I select empty textareas with CSS?

Tags: css, textarea, css-selectors

Is there a way that I can select a textarea such that `$('#id_of_textarea').val()` in jQuery will be `''`? I tried using `:empty`. I saw that CSS provides a way to select empty inputs because the text is in the `value` attribute (`[value=""]`). Is there an attribute for the text in a textarea?

I'm looking for a selector that will work with CSS, not just jQuery.

Comment: We all expect `textarea:empty` to just work. The feature parity of HTML form inputs is shocking.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

this works in recent browsers except edge (at the moment):

```
textarea:placeholder-shown {
  /* this should be active only when area is empty and placeholder shown */
}
```

so with jQuery for example you can pick all empty textareas:

```
$('textarea:placeholder-shown').val()
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:placeholder-shown

Comment: Works good! Do not forget to set the `placeholder` attribute to the `textarea`-element, otherwise this doesn't work.

Answer (score 24):

Best solution I can think of is a CSS 3 workaround. Set the field to required (and unset it on submit if need be). Then you can use

```
textarea:invalid { /* style here... probably want to remove box-shadow and such */ }
```

Comment: Amazing! Works on Safari, too. And Firefox. It's standards-based, though it makes me change my logic a bit.

Comment: Clever. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you're using React, then this is the solution:

```
textarea:not(:empty) {

 // Apply css here

}
```

For instance,

```
/* Apply style when textarea contains text */

textarea:not(:empty) {
  border: 6px solid blue;
  padding: 6px;
}
```

Working demo:
[Textarea - Select empty textarea using CSS](https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-haze-82px0)

**Note:** While this works perfectly in React (because of re-painting caused by state update), It does not provide the same response if implemented using Vanilla HTML + CSS.

Comment: React has both controlled and uncontrolled components, so your answer is inaccurate. This question isn't about React anyway though.

Comment: none of the above solutions worked for Firefox, but this one did! +1

Answer (score 0):

This works fine, as with input:

```
<textarea name="comment" id="comment" class="authority_body-input" data-val="{$form.comment}" onkeyup="this.setAttribute('data-val', this.value);">

textarea.authority_body-input:not([data-val=""]):not(:focus) {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use the `:empty` css pseudo-class.

See an example in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/diosney/Anr6U/2/).

In the example there is a button for dynamically add  new empty textareas to the DOM, so you can see that the new elements also are affected with the pseudo-class.

The code in the example was tested in Firefox 5.0, Opera 11.50 and Chromium 12.

Also, you can see a good description for the :empty pseudo-class [here](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-empty).

Comment: See the comment on the other person that suggested this. It only works initially, not once it has been input into.

Answer (score -2):

For those who are using AngularJS, you can use `ng-class` in your view to add a class to your textarea to know if it is empty or not.

HTML :

```
<textarea ng-model="myForm.myTextArea"
          ng-class="(myForm.myTextArea.length)?'not_empty':'empty'">
</textarea>
```

CSS :

```
textarea.empty {
    background-color:red;
}
textarea.not_empty {
    background-color:blue;
}
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zouzouv/qf3qm76d/).

Comment: According to my tests, jQuery `.val()` reflects the current text content, while jQuery `.text()` reflects the text between the tags in the original HTML. Furthermore, the CSS selector `:empty` checks the text between the tags in the original HTML (like jQuery `.text()`). CSS selector `[value=""]` doesn't seem to work at all. See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Anr6U/19/)