# Vertically centering a placeholder in a dynamically sized textarea

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm struggling to vertically center a placeholder in a textarea. The only available way to do it I have found so far is the line-height statement, but that doesn't allow me to place it centrally in textareas of multiple sizes.

```css
textarea {
  height: 113px;
}
textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #444;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 800%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<textarea placeholder="Some sample text."></textarea>
```

Comment: Do you want ONLY the placeholder to be vertically aligned this way, or all content entered into the textarea? Also, could you include some code of things you have tried?

Comment: So far, I have attempted this in CSS, but to no avail, as it only works for 1 height.


    textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder {

        color: #444;

        font-weight: bold;

        text-align: center;

        line-height: 800%;

        overflow: hidden;

    }

Oh, and only the placeholder. Everything else is fine as it is.

Comment: By multiple sizes do we mean a finite array of sizes eg.(200,300,500), or unlimited number of sizes?

Comment: It's an unlimited number of sizes, since the size of the textarea depends on the size of the div next to it, which could be 95px, 105px, 115px or anything greater.

Comment: In the chosen answer js code examines 10 times a second if the height of the textarea changed. If the height of the textarea is dependent on the div next to it, why would this be needed?

Comment: That part isn't needed, but the answer got me to my eventual solution. My question was too vague, so he wouldn't be expected to know my exact specifications, but the idea of using var statements in css wasn't one I knew about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is a little vague. I am assuming you want to vertical-align the placeholder no matter how far the user resizes it.

There is no `resize` event triggered by `textarea` when a user resizes it, so I have put the interesting code in a `setInterval`. Ten times a second the css variable `--line-height` is set to the height of the textarea. I've done it this way as it is not possible to set the css on a pseudo-element (`::placeholder`, etc).

[Browser Support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables) - Except IE11, all major browsers support `var()`.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  let $textarea = $('textarea');
  setInterval(function() {
    $textarea.get(0).style.setProperty("--line-height", $textarea.height() + 'px');
  }, 100);
});
```

```css
textarea {
  height: 113px;
  --line-height: 800%;
}

textarea::placeholder {
  color: #444;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: var(--line-height);
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea placeholder="Some sample text."></textarea>
```

Comment: Thank you! I know it was a little vague, not too used to this site, only a lurker normally.

Comment: No worries. I recommend reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to improve your questions going forward :)

Answer (score 2):

Just use textual svg as background image and position it to center. As there is not a really well-working `:empty` pseudo selector, you can use the `:invalid` instead to emulate the placeholder behavior, as mentioned in this post: [Can I select empty textareas with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7072576/can-i-select-empty-textareas-with-css)

```css
textarea:invalid {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='74' height='13' viewBox='0 0 74 13'><text transform='matrix(1 0 0 1 0 10)' font-size='12'>Write text here</text></svg>");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<textarea required></textarea>
```

Comment: I like this answer as a pure css solution with full browser support :)

Comment: Really slim. I like it

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with JavaScript and a span element. I've created a simple solution in a Fiddle:

```js
var txt = document.getElementById("txt");
var span = document.getElementById("span");

txt.onkeydown = function() {

  if (txt.value == "") {
    span.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    span.style.display = "none";
  }
}

setInterval(()=>{
 span.style.top = String(parseInt(txt.style.height)/2) + "px";
}, 10)
```

```css
textarea {
  height: 113px;
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 10px;
  color: #444;
  font-weight: bold;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="txt" onresize="console.log('test')"></textarea>
<span id="span">Placeholder</span>
```

I think there is no other option

EDIT 1:

Sorry, I din't see the answer of Richard Parnaby-King. But now you have 2 examples ;) 1 vanilla and 1 with JQuery

Comment: I like your answer, I'll compare both and see which works better, I'm not used to jQuery so might end up using yours.